# Maven ClassNotFoundException with mixed Java 1.6 and 1.7 name space

Tags: java, maven

I can't get maven to build a jar that I can run on my Ubuntu machine. It seems like the `.jar` is not being found by my `.jar`, no matter what I do.

What is really confusing me is that in the stack trace shows that an error with slash namespace is thrown, like in java 1.7, and then the cause is using java 1.6 namespace, I'm not sure if this might be related to the problem.

Any ideas on why I get the `ClassNotFound Exception` when I execute the `.jar`?

My **pom.xml** has all the right configurations to attach the dependencies to the `.jar` and to create the manifest:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rwanks.pepper</groupId>
    <artifactId>wiki-indexer</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>wiki-indexer</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
            <artifactId>lucene-benchmark</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
            <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <index>true</index>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.rwanks.pepper.WikipediaIndexer</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <mode>development</mode>
                            <url>${project.url}</url>
                            <key>value</key>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- or whatever version you use -->
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <useRepositoryLayout>false</useRepositoryLayout>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Stack trace:

```
java -jar target/wiki-indexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/benchmark/byTask/feeds/NoMoreDataException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2866)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1676)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.benchmark.byTask.feeds.NoMoreDataException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

The generated `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: hunter
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_91
Class-Path: commons-logging-1.2.jar lucene-core-5.4.0.jar lucene-query
 parser-5.4.0.jar lucene-sandbox-5.4.0.jar lucene-queries-5.4.0.jar lu
 cene-analyzers-common-5.4.0.jar lucene-benchmark-5.4.0.jar lucene-cod
 ecs-5.4.0.jar lucene-facet-5.4.0.jar lucene-highlighter-5.4.0.jar luc
 ene-join-5.4.0.jar lucene-memory-5.4.0.jar lucene-spatial-5.4.0.jar i
 cu4j-54.1.jar spatial4j-0.5.jar nekohtml-1.9.17.jar commons-compress-
 1.8.1.jar xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar solr-solrj-5.4.0.jar commons-io-2.4.ja
 r httpclient-4.4.1.jar httpcore-4.4.1.jar httpmime-4.4.1.jar zookeepe
 r-3.4.6.jar stax2-api-3.1.4.jar woodstox-core-asl-4.4.1.jar noggit-0.
 6.jar jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.7.jar slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.0.5
Main-Class: com.rwanks.pepper.WikipediaIndexer
key: value
url: http://maven.apache.org
mode: development
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The libraries are not in the expected class path.

`java -jar target/wiki-indexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` there you load the application jar in the subdirectory `target/`. But the classpath in the manifest `Class-Path: commons-logging-1.2.jar ...` states the libraries should be in the current directory.

Following should work as expected

```
cd target
java -jar wiki-indexer-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

**edit** As mentioned by [javapapo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1036433/javapapo) using the [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) could prevent such problems. The plugin could create one jar file containing the classes from all dependency jars.

A simple configuration might look like.

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: May I add that you could consider using [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) instead of maven-jar-plugin :)

Comment: @javapapo As you mention. I added a small snippet for the shade plugin. In case the requestor is not aware of it.

Comment: @javapapo I found about the shade plugin later on, but I'm not sure if that's optimal, I was kind of hoping to pick up the dependencies from my local .m2 folder or something more lightweight, but even if I added that folder to my class path i had no luck

Comment: @perrohunter If you run an application with `java -jar ...` you cannot specify the classpath with `java -cp ...` as it will be ignored in that case. You need to specify them in the `Class-Path:` header of the `MANIFEST.MF`. There you can specify the dependency libraries with a relative path (then they will not be found if you call the application not from the expected directory) or with an absolute path (then the application is not relocatable anymore and might not run on another machine).